# $f(x+y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y).$

Tags: functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$f(x+y)=f(xy)+f(x)+f(y).$$ Find $f$.

It's easy to show by induction that $f(0)=0$, $ f(n)=(5\cdot 2^{n-2}-1)\cdot f(1)$   for every integer $n\geq 2$. Also $f(-n)=f(-1)$. I try to prove that $f(x)>0$ for every $x>0$. Then $f$ would be increasing$

Comment: I got that $f(n)=(2^n-1)f(1)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(x+0)=f(0\cdot x)+f(x)+f(0)\implies f(0)=0.$$

Then
$$f(n+1)=f(n)+f(n)+f(1),f(0)=0$$
is a recurrence with the solution

$$f(n)=(2^n-1)f(1).$$

Next,

$$f(n+m)=(2^{n+m}-1)f(1)=(2^{nm}-1)f(1)+(2^n-1)f(1)+(2^m-1)f(1)$$ is only possible with $f(1)=0$, and $f(n)=0$.

This invalidates the conjecture $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

We also have

$$f(1-1)=f(-1)+f(1)+f(-1)$$ which gives $f(-1)=0$, and more generally we can show $f(-n)=0$.

Next, for any $x$,

$$f(x+n)=f(nx)+f(x)$$ but also

$$f(x+n)=f(x+n-1)+1=2f(x+n-1)=\cdots=2^nf(x)$$

so that

$$f(x)=\frac{f(nx)}{2^n-1}$$

and $f(x)=0$ for all rational $x$.

---

I guess that we can establish $f(x)=0$ for all algebraic numbers. For the transcendental ones, I am unsure.